# NSUserDefaults setobject method crashing

Tags: iphone, annotations, maps, ios7

I am trying to save an object inheriting MKAnnotation class in NSUserDefualts. It is working fine in iOS 6 but crashing in iOS7. Here is the code for saving:

```
    ParkHereAnnotation = [[catAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
    ParkHereAnnotation.title = @"Your Parked Here" ;
    ParkHereAnnotation.subtitle = @"";
    //ParkHereAnnotation.annotationType = location;
    ParkHereAnnotation.parkId = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"-1"];
    [ParkHereAnnotation setAnnotationType:location];
    [userDefaults setObject:ParkHereAnnotation forKey:@"ParkingAnnotation"];//Crashing here in iOS7 but not in iOS6.
```

Class:
Header

Header File

```
@interface catAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    NSString *parkId;
    enum MapAnnotationType annotationType;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, assign) enum MapAnnotationType annotationType;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *parkId;


@end
```

Implementation

```
@implementation catAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;
@synthesize annotationType;
@synthesize parkId;

-(id) init
{
    return self;
}

-(id) initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)inCoord
{
    coordinate = inCoord;
    return self;
}

@end
```

Object of class before setting is:
[image]

**Crash:**
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert non-property list object  for key ParkingAnnotation'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x31576e8b 0x3b8716c7 0x31576dcd 0x31ea7c21 0x126613 0x12708f 0x126f45 0x33d3155f 0x33d314fb 0x33d314cb 0x33d1d0f3 0x33d398cd 0x33d30b0d 0x33d2bc09 0x33d00f59 0x33cff747 0x31541f27 0x315413ef 0x3153fbdf 0x314aa541 0x314aa323 0x361e12eb 0x33d611e5 0xf811d 0x3bd6aab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS7 , you cant store class object in NSUserDefaults , You have to convert your class to a dictionary , array or data before saving in NSuserDefaults.
NSUserDefault is actually a plist which stores all the data in Library folder. So if you want to save anything in it you have to follow property list types.

Comment: To be clear, in iOS 6 you can't either. The difference is that iOS 6 silently fails to save your data, whereas iOS 7 lets you know.

Answer (score 3):

Your model class is not a property list content. In userdefault you can only save plist contents like string, bool , dict, array etc. To save a custom object you need to write coder/encoder methods like:(example)

```
 -(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:_title];
    [coder encodeObject:_album];
    [coder encodeObject:_pathURL];
    [coder encodeObject:_daysOfGoal];
    [coder encodeObject:_numberOfTimesPlayed];
    [coder encodeObject:_infoString];
    [coder encodeObject:_duration];
    [coder encodeObject:_numberOfTimesPlayed];
    [coder encodeObject:_dosage];
    [coder encodeObject:_creationDate];
    [coder encodeObject:_type];
    [coder encodeBool:_isAutosuggestion forKey:@"isAutosuggestion"];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        [self setTitle:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setAlbum:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setPathURL:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setDaysOfGoal:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setNumberOfTimesPlayed:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setInfoString:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setDuration:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setNumberOfTimesPlayed:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setDuration:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setDosage:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setCreationDate:[coder decodeObject]];
        [self setIsAutosuggestion:[coder decodeBoolForKey:@"isAutosuggestion"]];

    }

    return self;
}
```

You need to add these method to save in userdefault.